# Estimating the remainder of Taylor series written in Lagrange form

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

> Given the function
> $$f(x) = \ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$$
> Show that the error $f(1/3) - T_n(1/3)$ is at most $55/7776$

#### My attempt

Remainder Term = $[f^{(5)}(x) = 24/(1+x)^5 + 24/(1-x)^5]x^5/5!$

I am having difficulty in putting a limit on the $f^{(5)}(x)$ term so that I can calculate the maximum possible error....any tricks I can use here?

Comment: I edited to improve formatting and make the title more descriptive. See [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

HINT:  The remainder term is given by $f^{(5)}(c)\cdot(\frac{1}{3})^5/5!$ $\;\;$ where $0<c<\frac{1}{3}$ and

$f^{(5)}(c)=24\big(\frac{1}{(1+c)^5}+\frac{1}{(1-c)^5}\big)\le24\big(1+\frac{1}{(2/3)^5}\big)$.

Comment: That's what I don't get, how did you get that $f^5(c)$ is at most $24(1+1/(2/3)^5)$

Comment: I'm using that $\frac{1}{(1+x)^5}$ is decreasing and $\frac{1}{(1-x)^5}$ is increasing on $[0,\frac{1}{3}]$.

Comment: Oh okay, I see that now ... Thanks a lot